# Remove Special Character Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently I try this expression /[^\w\s]/gi in javascript. However, it doesn't remove _ underscore. How to remove underscore? I want to remove these special characters 
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~

```
    var text = reasonTxt.GetText(); var textFull = text.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
```

Comment: `_` is a word character...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_` is considered as word character.
so you need to negate this also.

```
var text = reasonTxt.GetText(); var textFull = text.replace(/[^\w\s]|_/gi, '');
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gDG07a/3)

```js
let str = "vivek #$ asbc &12341236~!@#$%^&   _    !#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~+_";



console.log(str.replace(/[^\w\s]|_/gi, ""));
```

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi stop harassing people. No one copied your answer.

Comment: @YvetteColomb: Well, not trying to harass/offend anyone. Check this answer's revision history, which was first incorrectly answered, and after I posted my answer, this answer was edited to **exactly** use my answer. Is that fair? Hope SO addresses this fairly.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I have checked it and the timestamps. Drop it and don't ping me or comment here  about it again. If you have an issue take it to meta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

if you only want letters and numbers

```
var text = reasonTxt.GetText(); var textFull = text.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/g, '');
```

if you only want letters

```
var text = reasonTxt.GetText(); var textFull = text.replace(/[^A-Za-z]+/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is almost right but since `_` already comes in `\w` (`\w` is same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) hence you will have to explicitly put check for `_` and modify your regex to this,

```
[^\w\s]|_
```

Change your code to this,

```
var text = reasonTxt.GetText(); var textFull = text.replace(/[^\w\s]|_/gi, '');
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iTGdy3/1)

Answer (score 0):

var text = reasonTxt.GetText(); var textFull = text.replace(/[^\w\s]|_/gi, '');